# Django - How to filter a ListView by user without using CBV?

Tags: python, django, listview, django-class-based-views

Is it possible to do this?  I've been looking for quite a while, but every solution I've seen involves subclassing `ListView` which I don't want to do.  I'm sure there's a way to filter results by user without having to resort to class-based views, I just can't seem to find good information on it, am I missing something?

I've tried a few things similar to this, but I don't think it's going to work the way I'm trying, and the only other way I've seen is with CBV:

```
url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Game.objects.filter(user=User.user), template_name = 'userprofile.html')),
```

Comment: The magic question: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send a request to view you have already instance of the current user in the request:

**views.py**

```
def my_not_cb_view(request):
    user = request.user 
    games = Game.objects.filter(user=User.user)
    context = {'games': games, 'user': user}
    render_to_response(request, 'user profile.html', context=context)
```

**urls.py**

`url(r'^$', my_not_cb_view)`